# Import csv to SQLServer when there are spaces after the text qualifier

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, sql-import-wizard

I have a csv file with a column GeoCodes. This uses " as text qualifier.

I am trying to import this into SQLServer using the SQL Server Import Wizard.
The problem with the data is, if there is no GeoCode the csv file will sometimes output the GeoCode as " " and then several spaces. This errors when trying to import the data as it picks up the data within the text qualifier and then there are these spaces before the next comma delimiter.

An example of the data below. The Pontypandy row is the row that errors.

```
Place      ,Geo Codes           ,Type                          
Northpole  ,"90.0000,0.0000    ",Pole                          
Southpole  ,"-90.0000,0.0000   ",Pole                          
Pyramids   ,"29.9765,31.1313   ",BigTriangle                   
France     ,"                  ",Country                       
Pontypandy ," "                 ,City
```

I have to use the text qualifiers as there is a comma in the GeoCodes.

I have no say on how the data is sent to me and therefore have to deal with the data as is.

As a work around I have to do a find and replace on the data in notepad first before importing. This adds an extra step to the job that hopefully isn't needed.

Is there anyway I can get around the **" " spaces** during the import?

As an extra note, I don't currently have access to SSIS but if it can be done in there any easier then please answer with that as it could help me justify getting SSIS (I might have to remove this comment later if I have to show it to my manager).

Comment: A quick fix would be to use Notepad++ and use Find / Replace for "\s, to ",. I don't see how or why your CSV is doing that. Are you manually putting the quotes in? Usually when a csv is quoted ALL columns are quoted.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I'm using a similar work around. As I will have to do this regularly I am looking for something a bit more standard in the import. If it can be done.

Comment: And not sure why the data is coming out like that. I think it comes out with a " around everything when nothing has been input. I think it comes out wrong when someone has deleted data. I don't handle that system though so can't change anything there

Comment: If you have powershell you can automate the cleanup and the import in one script

Comment: @Jimbo Thanks, I might have a look at that.

Comment: Can you change it so the comma's are not used in the CSV?  When a CSV is string qualified, the commas become less useful.  When using text-qualified fields in a CSV file, it is best to use a pipe delimiter `|`.  If that is not a possibility, you can use a pre-processor to change all commas contained within a string-qualified section into placeholders, such as `{COMMA}` and then do a `Bulk Insert` of the CSV into a Table using Commas `,` as the delimiter and then replacing those Placeholders back to their original character.

Comment: @GoldBishop the data is sent to me and can't be changed. I have a work around on the file before import as it is, so replacing that work around with another won't add anything. I do realise that cleaning that data before producing the csv would be ideal but unfortunately that is out of my control.

Comment: ChrisM...then bulk insert the CSV with the line terminator `\r` or `\n` as a row into a single field table, using a view.  Once you have every row within the CSV into a table, then you can clean up the data into the requisite structure.  The key is getting the CSV into the database, whether it is row or field based.

Comment: @GoldBishop Where would I use the line terminator? Would that still import the columns after the GeoCodes part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data really is the way you show above you can use fixed width format. Import the data as is and replace the " afterwards. This is not the best solution.

Much better: pipe the import file through sed before importing. This is not only much faster, but in all cases, when data is larger than your RAM the only easy way (OK, there are some other). All you need is sed at operation system level. If you can copy the executable somewhere it's all you need. If you want to replace "[any number of blanks], with ", this is the regex should be:

```
cat myfile.txt|sed -b -e "s/\" *,/\",/">yournewfile.txt
```

The regex is easy once you get the idea: 
 - s means Substitute, 
 - /first /second/ means look for first and replace with second, 
 - \" is the escaped " (because of DOS)
 - Space and * means any number of spaces
 - , means ,

On a lot of systems sed is still there (cygwin). Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Two methods of Bulk Insert

1. Row-based Bulk Insert

   - *Most Useful when you have string-qualified columns in CSV*
   - You will need to first create a table with two-fields: `identity` & `varchar(max)`; `identity` will signify the row-count & `varchar(max)` will be your row data
   - Create a view that only selects the `varchar(max)` field from the table above

Bulk Insert syntax will look something like this:

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.v_SalesOrderDetail  
FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.csv'  
    WITH   (  
        ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'  
    );
```

2. Columnar-based Insert:

   - Most use this widely but is only useful and reliable when there are no string qualified columns.
   - Use most common Bulk Insert syntax with `RowTerminator` and `LineTerminator` options

#### References:

- Bulk-Insert Syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#examples
- Bulk-Insert with View: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250(v=sql.105).aspx
- Bulk-Insert with Table: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187086(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @ChrisM Make sure you use the appropriate `Char` key for identifying the row or column delimiters.  This will help with dissociating the unique differences between Unix and Windows formatted files